# Tar exclusion list doesn't work anymore after upgrading to Debian stretch

Tags: debian, backup, tar, upgrade

I wrote a backup script a long time ago, which uses [this part of the tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_49.html):

> You may give multiple `--exclude' options.
>
> `--exclude-from=file`
>
> `-X file`
>
> Causes tar to ignore files that match the patterns listed in file.

My tar command is the following:

```
includesFile=include.txt
excludesFile=exclude.txt
tar zcpf - . -T ${includesFile} -X ${excludesFile} | openssl des3 -salt | dd of=out.bak
```

This is `include.txt`:

```
/etc/
/var/
/usr/
/data/
/opt/
/root
```

This is `exclude.txt`

```
/data/webapp/webapp-data/*
/var/cache/*
/var/lib/dpkg/*
/usr/bin/*
/usr/share/locale/*
```

It used to work very well. Recently I noticed that the size of the archive increased significantly, and by switching to verbose `tar` made me see that it's including the `webapp-data` directory which is huge. For some reason it's not being excluded anymore.

The last thing I did is upgrading from [Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/tar) to [Debian Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/tar). The version change is minor, I wonder whether it's the reason.

I tried changing `/data/webapp/webapp-data/*` to `/data/webapp/webapp-data/**`, but that didn't help.

Why is the exclusion list not working anymore?

Comment: The manpage gives the create syntax as `tar -c [-f ARCHIVE] [OPTIONS] [FILE...]`, I'm not sure the `[OPTIONS]` can come after the `[FILE...]` argument(s) like that - have you tried `tar zcpf - -T ${includesFile} -X ${excludesFile} -- .`?

Comment: @steeldriver I'll try that now and report.

Comment: @steeldriver Nope... didn't work either...

Comment: why use `| dd of=out.bak` rather than just `> out.bak`?   BTW is `/data/webapp/webapp-data/` the actual directory, or a symlink pointing to the directory?    And is it failing to exclude anything in that `exclude.txt` file, or just the webapp-data directory?   Also, try just `/data/webapp/webapp-data/` without the `*` wildcards...IIRC that will exclude the directory and everything under it with `tar`.

Comment: these lines `includesFile=include.txt` and `excludesFile=exclude.txt` doesn't contain any file content you set and passing to `tar` command!!

Comment: @cas I'll try these when I get back home today.

Comment: @AFSHIN I'm sorry, I don't understand what you said at all. I read your comment 5 times and couldn't get a statement from it. Please rephrase.

Comment: You should probably remove the `.` from your command, as if your current directory is `/` you will be also tarring `./data/webapp...` and this will not be matched by your excludes which begin with `/`

Comment: @cas Didn't work...

Comment: @meuh Didn't work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (finally) have figured out the problem and was able to solve it. It's a combination of multiple things, including that `excludes` are given as a wild-card (while before asking the question I didn't do that... now that doesn't work anymore). This is the command that works:

```
includesFile=include.txt
excludesFile=exclude.txt
tar -zcpf - --absolute-names -X ${excludesFile} -T ${includesFile} | openssl des3 -salt | dd of=out.bak
```

And definitely, excludes are given in this form:

```
/var/cache/*
/var/lib/dpkg/*
/usr/bin/*
/usr/share/locale/*
/proc/*
/sys/*
```

And includes:

```
/etc/
/var/
/usr/
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with tar exclusions after upgrading from Debian Jessie to Stretch and I fixed it by just changing the commandline parameters order

from:

`tar cvzpf backup.tar.gz /DirToBackup1 /DirToBackup2 --exclude-from=/path/to/backup_exclude.txt`

to:

`tar cvzpf backup.tar.gz --exclude-from=/path/to/backup_exclude.txt /DirToBackup1 /DirToBackup2`

my backup_exclude.txt looks like this

`/var/log/*
/cache/*
/.cache/*`

(refering to the end of the page of
https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_49.html)

Comment: I didn't have any success with this... especially because I'm piping to openssl... I don't know where to put that `-` that takes care of piping...